# Black line in certain videos?

Tags: video-standards, distortion

Here are few screencaps from different sources:

- Bleach 170:

  [image: Bleach 170]
- Bleach 297, where 16:9 episode actually used 4:3 material in one reminiscence scene (they even animated the black bars) - poor source material?

  [image: Bleach 297]
- Xena the Warrior Princess:

  [image: Xena]
- Finally a Youtube video:

If you look closely, each of these frames contains a thin black line near the bottom, or in the case of the Youtube video, near the top. The line spans about 60% of the video width. **What is it and why is it there?** Is it used for some kind of calibration?

Answer (score 2):

The first anime pic is throwing me off, but it seems to be an artifact of how interlaced analog signals were [structured](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/480i) and displayed.

> For analog NTSC there is a total of 525 scanning lines of which
>   originally 483 lines were visible (241.5 visible lines + 21 lines of
>   vertical blanking per field)

**Update**: this answer at the electronics site gives the [full picture](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/98922/why-there-is-625-lines-pal-in-t-v-scanning-or-odd-lines).